# Ionic- How to play only one media object from multiple objects

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

[image]

There are three Ionic-native media objects in the screen.
I make a code that play the selected one.

```
    play(filename)
    {
       this.curr_playing_file = this.createAudioFile(savfilename);
       this.curr_playing_file.play();
    }

   createAudioFile(filename): MediaObject {
        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {  //ios
          console.log(filename.replace(/^file:\/\//, ''));
          return this.media.create(filename.replace(/^file:\/\//, ''));    
        } else {  // android
          return this.media.create(filename);
      } 
   }
```

when i click three of them , they are playing at the same time.
I want to play only one at that time.
Please help how can i solve this problem efficiently.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check if any other audio is playing and if any other audio is playing you need to stop it and release it before playing the other file

```
if (this.curr_playing_file.mediaStatus == 2)
{
this.curr_playing_file.stop();
this.curr_playing_file.Release();
}
this.media.create(filename);
```